# Can I remove Response Schema table. Just keep Example Value

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-ui, slate, widdershins

I am creating an docs Api with Swagger 3.0.0 by YAML, convert to markdown by Widdershins, and then build to HTML by Slate.

Can I remove or hide Response Schema table and keep showing Example value.
Now I have just done empty the Response Schema table. It still show title "Response Schema" of that table.

Can you guys help me to solve this problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try editing responses.def? I believe that is the template that generates the table you are talking about. I think the table starts on line 43.

Path: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/widdershins/templates/openapi3/responses.def